# how to scroll my map in java?

Tags: java, dictionary, scroll

Firstly, happy new year all.

Ive got a

```
    int[] map = new int[2550];
```

and in that array I place the id of a block at that pos, so for example if the top left block in the map has a id of one

```
    map[0] = 1
```

Now I'm trying to think how I would scroll my map now, as I render the map like so -

```
  for(int y = 0 ;y < current.height;y++){
for(int x = 0 ; x < current.width;x++){
    Block block = current.getBlock(x, y);
    g.drawImage(block.texture, x * 30 , y * 30);
  }
}
```

How would I scroll the map? to make it so for example the block that was at 0,0 is now at 0,1 or whatever. Thanks for the help.

Edit: Im using LWJGL and slick2d to do my rendering and stuff, so I cant use Swing or AWT.

Answer (score 1):

Scrolling is simply drawing all your graphics with a variable offset. Let there be a current scroll position:

```
int scrollX, scrollY;
```

Update these variables (and redraw) whenever you want to scroll. In your drawing routine, change the loop like this:

```
for (int y = 0; y < current.height; y++) {
  for (int x = 0; x < current.width; x++) {
    Block block = current.getBlock(x, y);
    g.drawImage(block.texture, x * 30 - scrollX, y * 30 - scrollY);
  }
}
```

Now, that's basic scrolling, and that will work. However, if you are adding scrolling you probably are planning to have maps much larger than the screen. In that case, it is inefficient to draw the entire map every time. Therefore, instead of iterating over the entire map, you iterate over only the *visible* portion of the map, which is not too complex:

```
int startX = Math.max(scrollX / 30, 0);
int startY = Math.max(scrollY / 30, 0);
int limitX = Math.min((scrollX + windowWidth ) / 30 + 1, current.width );
int limitY = Math.min((scrollX + windowHeight) / 30 + 1, current.height);
for (int y = startY; y < limitY; y++) {
  for (int x = startX; x < limitX; x++) {
    Block block = current.getBlock(x, y);
    g.drawImage(block.texture, x * 30 - scrollX, y * 30 - scrollY);
  }
}
```

The `min` and `max` are to avoid trying to draw tiles outside the bounds of the map. Note that this is exactly the same loop as before, except that the loop bounds have been changed.

By the way, you should also put the size of your tiles in a variable, so that if you ever decide to resize your tiles, or add zooming, you don't have to change code all over the place:

```
static final int TILE_SIZE = 30;
...
g.drawImage(block.texture, x * TILE_SIZE - scrollX, y * TILE_SIZE - scrollY);
```